# How to add additional PropertyDescriptor to ICustomTypeDescriptor AFTER setting DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

**Qeustion:**

Is it possible to add an additional `PropertyDescriptor` to the `PropertyDescriptorCollection` of an `ICustomTypeDescriptor` after `DataConext` has been set?

**Details:**

I am creating a new class which implements `ICustomTypeDescriptor` with the goal of dynamically adding new Properties to this class at runtime, and binding them to a WPF application.

For example, a user may define a new property through a scripting language (eg. Lua) while the app is running, and I would like XAML to be able to Bind to that Property.

The issue I am running into is that if I add a property AFTER the DataContext has been set, the Binding to XAML does not work; it does not attempt to call associated `PropertyDescriptor.GetValue` method.

I believe this issue is that shortly after setting the DataContext to my `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, its implementation of `ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties` is called, at which point I create `PropertyDescriptor` for all known Properties. I then later add new Properties, but don't have the ability to add new `PropertyDescriptor` for them.

**Code:**

I have trimmed down the code a bit here to make it easier to read, removing a lot of the boiler-plate stuff.

The idea in this example is that the first text field is Bound to a dynamically created property, which is defined during construction, and the second text field is Bound to a property that won't exist until the Button is clicked.

The property created when the button is clicked only gets DataBound properly if I set the DataContext to something new.

```
public class MyCustomType : ICustomTypeDescriptor, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Dictionary<string, object> Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MyCustomType()
    {
        Properties.Add("CustomProp", "What up, world?");
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public void CreateOrSetProperty(string name, object val)
    {
        Properties[name] = val;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(name);
    }

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        List<PropertyDescriptor> props = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in Properties)
        {
            props.Add(new MyCustomTypePropertyDescriptor(entry.Key, attributes));
        }

        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(props.ToArray());
    }

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        return ((ICustomTypeDescriptor)this).GetProperties(null);
    }

    class MyCustomTypePropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        public MyCustomTypePropertyDescriptor(string name, Attribute[] attrs)
            : base(name, attrs)
        {
        }

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            return ((MyCustomType)component).Properties[Name];
        }

        public override bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

         public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            ((MyCustomType)component).Properties[Name] = value;
        }
    }
}

public partial class Page5
{
    public Page5()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnAddProperty_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // A static resource defined in XAML used as the DataContext for both text blocks.
        MyCustomType c = Resources["MyCustomTypeData"] as MyCustomType;

        // Create a new property which is already being referenced in a DataBind in XAML but 
        // prior to this function being called, did not exist.
        c.CreateOrSetProperty("AnotherProp", "Another Property!");

        // If I clear the DataContext and set it back to the previous value it triggers 
        // ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties to get called again, and the property gets
        // Bound. If I don't do this, it fails.
        //MyTextBlock2.DataContext = null;
        //MyTextBlock2.DataContext = c;
    }
}
```

```
<Page.Resources>
    <WpfApplication1:MyCustomType x:Key="MyCustomTypeData"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock DataContext="{StaticResource MyCustomTypeData}" x:Name="MyTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CustomProp}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="32" Background="Black" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBlock DataContext="{StaticResource MyCustomTypeData}" x:Name="MyTextBlock2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding AnotherProp}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="32" Background="Black" Foreground="White"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnAddProperty" Content="Add Additional Property" Click="BtnAddProperty_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question. However, I guess it maybe part of your problem that you use a Dictionary in a binding expression. In my opinion the collection which will be bound in xaml should be a type derrived from ObservableCollection in order to own the ability to notify view when collection change.

Comment: I am binding through an instance of ICustomTypeDescriptor, and writing a custom PropertyDescriptor. The dictionary should be irrelevant I believe. It is just how I chose to store my Property data.